# php exec ffmpeg how to get errors

Tags: ffmpeg

when i run

```
exec("ffmpeg -i $flv -y -f mjpeg -ss 00:00:05 -s 120x90 -vframes 1 -an thumb.jpg",$error);
```

$error return's empty value 
but when i run this command using cron job
this one send a notification email to me which contain informations like

> FFmpeg version 0.5.2, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
>    configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
>    libavutil     49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0
>    libavcodec    52.20. 1 / 52.20. 1
>    libavformat   52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0
>    libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
>    libavfilter    0. 4. 0 /  0. 4. 0
>    libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1
>    libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
>    built on Jun 13 2010 23:44:18, gcc: 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)

I need to be able to get those errors in php so i can know if the thumb was created or not

Thanks.

Comment: how to do error handling in ffmpeg ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redirect the output with `2>&1`

`exec("ffmpeg -i $flv -y -f mjpeg -ss 00:00:05 -s 120x90 -vframes 1 -an thumb.jpg 2>&1",$error);`

Comment: I know this is an old question but I always find it useful to also get the FFMPEG report when running some command. Therefor I use something like this: `$cmd = 'ffmpeg -i ' . $task . $codec . $path . ' -report -hide_banner -loglevel error 2>&1';  $r = exec($cmd, $errors);`   where -report  generates an extensive report in the root directory. For bigger projects I always throw in a logging system like: `$log = file_put_contents($logFile, $cmd . PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);` just to have everything in one place and commented nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Building on top of Mauro's answer. A clean way to detect errors will be adding the following options `-hide_banner` and `-loglevel error`.

```
exec("ffmpeg -i $flv -y -f mjpeg -ss 00:00:05 -s 120x90 -vframes 1 -an thumb.jpg -hide_banner -loglevel error 2>&1", $errors);
```

`exec()` will always assign an array of strings to the second parameter in this case `$errors`, each element corresponding to a different error, so you can simply print or handle each error using a loop:

```
foreach($errors as $next) {
    //handle error
    echo $next;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer comes almost 6 year after question, but newer versions have an option `-hide_banner`.

**From man page**

> -hide_banner
>
> Suppress printing banner.
>
> All FFmpeg tools will normally show a copyright notice, build options and library versions. This option can be used to suppress printing this information.

Also you can use the option `-loglevel` to define what kind of message (errors, warning, info, debug) would you want to show.