# How can I use ffmpeg with PHP's exec( ) command?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I'm running Max OS 10.7, MAMP (PHP 5.3.6), with FFMPEG installed. I want to convert videos from one format to another. The following entered into Terminal works fine:

```
 ffmpeg -i /path/video.wmv /path/video.flv
```

The file video.wmv is converted to video.flv. Great! Now, this PHP line DOESN'T work:

```
 exec('ffmpeg -i /path/video.wmv /path/video.flv');
```

Why? I've spent many hours reading up on this and I still can't figure out what is wrong. I have read the other discussions on this topic and there is no clear answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated! (PHP safe_mode is off).

Comment: Check your `error.log`, make sure the binary is in the path, or add `2>&1` to receive some details on your wrongdoings.

Comment: This is propably a problem with permissions. The user which PHP or Apache is using doesn't have the permissions to access/write to the destinations.

Comment: File permissions are wide open. It seems like there are lots of people that have the same issue. I would expect that any command that I can enter into terminal can be used as an argument to exec(). Clearly, this isn't the case.

Comment: @JohnAnderson: The shell exec is running in might not be the same shell of your terminal, so you can't expect that out of the box.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php exec ffmpeg how to get errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272604/php-exec-ffmpeg-how-to-get-errors)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would double check that the path to ffmpeg is correct. Also, take a look at the output to see if has anything useful, like this:

```
exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i $srcFile $destFile 2>&1", $output);
var_dump($output);
```